# Validate forms on both sides or only in the server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, frontend, backend

I have a question about forms validation in JS. I know that the most part of the inputs of an app must be validated on the server side, but if you also do it in the client side, you will be avoiding unnecesary requests to the server.

In the other hand, the logic of your data validation will be exposed in your client code (in my opinion there will be more chance to bypass the app security), and also, there will be code repetition (in the server and client) and a double check if all is correct, which is not the best performance.

**Is there any standard?** Until now, I have been doing all this stuff in the backend, but I am a little curious about this.

I would really appreciate the suggestion (**list of pros and cons**, if necessary) of an experienced programmer.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that is opinion-based, I am asking for standards and a list of pros and cons, just to make this as better as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cybercreeps can attack your server-side applications with maliciously crafted requests. They don't have to use your client side code to do this, instead they can hack together their own client side scripts. Therefore, your server code MUST do all validation necessary to protect your application against attack. It CANNOT rely on client side validation for security and integrity.

Your client side application can also validate its inputs. For example, it can warn the user if they put their given name into a date field, or make other similar mistakes. You do this as a courtesy to your user, to make your app easier to use.

Comment: So to summarize, in the client side we can make some parts of the validation that is also made in the server-side (because js can be disabled by the user), just to give faster feedbacks to the client?

Comment: Exactly right. Read up on OWASP to understand more about server validation and cybercreeps.

Answer (score 2):

I am not so experienced but my opinion is that I would do validation on the client side mostly only if it affects the UI/UX. It can be something regarding the permissions, so the UI gets to disable some stuff for example. The other aspect is the data type, this can be restricted in the client side but this is not validation.

Comment: Yes, until now I have been doing something like this. I don't validate the data types, I do it in the server side too, but if for example there is an action which is for only allowed premium users, I do it in the client, just to alert the user as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/) you can find a list of most common vulnerabilities of information systems. If you don't validate on the FE side, there's a risk of XSS attacks. On the other hand, if you don't validate on the BE side, there's a risk of Injection, Sensitive Data Exposure, etc.

So, to summarize my point, I think that the best would be to validate on both sides.

P.S. this is just my personal opinion, and I am a **junior** developer.

Comment: Why front-end validations avoid XSS attacks? I mean, if the client code is manipulable, isn't is safer to validate the data with regex in the server side, and then email the admin with the hacker's ip for example? (Not sure)

Comment: If the attacker is able to change the DOM structure in any way, it's a XSS attack. The <script> can be stored let's say in the js variable, and then in some point, you need to show what's inside the variable, and that's when the script would be executed. If you're only concerned about DB, maybe it's ok to validate just on the server side.

Comment: Client side validation is basically usability sugar. An attacker could easily change or bypass any validation you put in. The backend validation serves a security purpose - not allowing a request which is invalid from happening. So generally you need both but the backend checks are security critical and need to be thoroughly tested and robust.